# JSON format conversion

Tags: javascript, json

I need suggestions about simple json conversion. Am listing here what I have and what I need.

SOURCE FORMAT

```
{
    "EnglishLiterals": [{
        "identifier": "prefix1",
        "value": "I really enjoyed reading your website."
    }, {
        "identifier": "suffix1",
        "value": "I hope to make it well."
    }],
    "VietnameseLiterals": [{
        "identifier": "prefix1",
        "value": "ABCD"
    }, {
        "identifier": "suffix1",
        "value": "WXYZ"
    }]
}
```

TARGET FORMAT

```
"EnglishLiterals": {
        "prefix1": "I really enjoyed reading your website.",
        "suffix1": "I hope to make it well."
    },
    "VietnameseLiterals": {
        "prefix1": "ABCD",
    "suffix1": "WXYZ"
    }
```

Can I use plain simple Javascript for this?
Basically the value in first format becomes the key in second, and this is where I am struggling.

Please help.

Comment: Such problems are already solved in SO.. did you try browsing for sometime..?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. You are working with plain old JavaScript objects. Yes, you can use JavaScript for this. That's what it does for a living--manipulating objects. Also, your "target format" is not a valid JavaScript value--did you mean to enclose it in curly braces? Please also indent it properly.

Comment: @torazaburo nice you pointed out that this is not JSON. I have come across many users here who just confuse the hell out of JSON and JavaScript object.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy can you please give us one of best example for JSON and Javascript object???

Comment: @DarshakGajjar JSON is a string .. it's just a representation of a object. You cannot perform any object related operation on it.. say like using `.` operator or looping it's `key` .. `var obj = {name: "Raj"}` is a object and `var jObj ='{name: "Raj"}' ` is JSON(note the quotes that wrap the object). Also when you do `alert(obj)` you get a object something like [object Object] but when you do `alert(jObj)` you get the string `'{name: "Raj"}'`. When you do a JSON.stringify on a object you get JSON.

Answer (score 0):

> I need suggestions

Start off by writing a simple loop over all the properties in the object, and print out their value. If you don't know how to get all the properties in an object, the suggestion is to go back and review the tutorials and books you are working with (hint: `Object.keys`, or `for...in` might help). You should be able to take it from there, since you already know how to set an object property using a variable, using `obj[key]`.

> Can I use plain simple JavaScript for this?

What else would you use? Why would you think JavaScript couldn't handle this?